# I would like to buy references in order to review and study mathematics

Tags: soft-question, education

I am an ESL learner and most of the time I am able to understand English but In my courses, we don't study mathematics, and I think that it is a mistake or wrong.

1-What are really the best sources (book or books) to study and review completely high school mathematics?
-titles
-authors
-edition
-publishers

2-What are really the best sources (book or books) to study and review completely college mathematics?
-titles
-authors
-edition
-publishers

3-What are really the best sources (book or books) to study and review completely university mathematics; the basic courses before to study a specialty in a university for example. I ignore how matematics courses work in an American, Canadian or English university.
-titles
-authors
-edition
-publishers

4-What is or are the best calculator or calculators? I mean software applications used to calculate or the usual electronic device used in university courses? I know DreamCalc but are there others? I know what is spreadsheet but is there a better thing that I can use? I know of the IrisPen to develop solutions to math problems using a computer but is there a better thing to use?

I sincerely thank you to develop extensively comments and suggest really good books, products, software applications and os on.

Comment: 4. If you can, get *Mathematica* or Maple.

Comment: I don't see the difference between 2 and 3. The calculus is a must, but what other stuff you should study depends on your background and what you really want to do.

Comment: Some basic linear algebra is a must, too.

Comment: Dear @J.M.: I'm not sure that I understand your recommendation of Mathematica or Maple --- I've had to use the former for my physics courses, but almost never in a mathematics course. (Also, there are open-source alternatives that certainly handle basic functionality if it is necessary.)

Comment: @Akhil: He asked for software, and he doesn't necessarily have to get the latest versions (I actually think they've been piling *Mathematica* up a bit too much ever since version 6 myself; I've been happy sticking with 5.2 and have found I didn't really need the shiny new stuff too much.). In any event, spreadsheets can't do symbolics, but yeah, there are FOSS computing environments (though apart from Octave, I haven't used any of those to say something worthwhile).

Comment: @3-f-a-10: I am good at answering these types of questions, you should see my book collection!  It would be very helpful to me if you could please state what your current level of knowledge is, what topics you are studying, etc... Your plan is very ambitious, and I think it's great you want to get all the references at once, but if I could give you some advice: don't get every book at once, just get one book at a time and work really hard on that book.  You will probably end up buying a lot of books you won't read otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Hi
1) "High School" Math really varies from region to region, but if you aim is the review for University, you should get any book on analytic geometry, or "college" algebra.

2,3) Calculus and Linear algebra make up the bulk of first year University Math.  Any old edition of "James Stewart Calculus" should suit you fine.  I think David Lay's "Linear algebra and it's applications" is also pretty good.

4) Most University math is done without a calculator, but some students purchase the computer software "Maple" as an aid.  Maple is easier to learn than other programs like Mathamatica, and you shouldn't need anything more advanced than this for intro college/university

Comment: "Maple is easier to learn than other programs like Mathamatica" - YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

At first when I had the idea to ask this question, I tought about books such as Schaum's Outline of College Mathematics and other books of the same kind for high school and university mathematics courses; then I found out this Website and I had the idea to demand to "math experts." I knew Mathematica, this great math software application, but I am also happy that you talked about Maple that also really seems to be a great tool too. Thank you to tell me that Maple is less complex. At least, it seems that they developed portals and resources for students. It "sounds" great. In practice it is sometimes "another game." In my opinion, I suppose that someone who buys the IrisPen to develop math problems on a computer and on paper, and that is also enable to use an application such as Maple 14 Academic or another version is really in a good position to be good at solving math problems and tasks of the like.

Comment: Myself, I'm a fan of [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net). There is even a full version running on Android, on my phone and tablet.

Answer (score 0):

A nice starting place is the [collection of notes](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/~maths/notes/wchen/ln.html) by William Chen. It covers most of the undergraduate curriculum (and somewhat before) in a really accessible way. The [Trillia group](http://www.trillia.com/) has a collection of nice texts too.